# Given the system function, how can i tell if it is a lowpass or a highpass filter?

Tags: transfer-function, dsp, low-pass, system, high-pass-filter

If i am given the system function of a FIR digital filter obtained by recursive

frequency sampling design procedure., how can i tell if it is a lowpass, highpass, or bandpass filter?

[image: For example,]

Comment: Give an example.

Comment: 1) Find textbook 2) Open textbook 3) Read textbook 4) ... ? 5) Profit

Comment: No seriously, that question would work well with an example, but as it is now, nobody will write you a full course on filters.

Comment: The DC response (of an FIR) is the sum of the coefficients. If that is 0 it's a high pass filter.  Possibly bandpass, but at least you can eliminate low pass.

Answer (score 1):

Zeroes tell which frequencies the system attenuates and poles tell which frequencies the system doesn't attenuate. If you get zeroes close to (re=1,im=0), the system doesn't allow low frequencies. If you have a pole over there it means the system just allows low frequencies to pass.

Why the point (re=1,im=0) corresponds to low frequency????. The line connecting this point and (0,0) makes 0 angle w.r.t real axis. 0 angle is low frequency.

Similarly you can proceed for analysing higher and medium frequency range by considering suitable angle on z-plane. This just gives you a rough idea..

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is:

- Low pass filter only allows low frequencies to pass
- high pass only allows high frequencies to pass
- band pass only allows frequencies between a range to pass.

[image]

Consider that following circuit. If Z1 is a resistor and Z2 is a capacitor then the magnitude of the response becomes $$\frac{1}{(1^2 + (wCR)^2)^{0.5}}$$

At low frequencies, $$wCR << 1$$, the capacitor acts as an open and the voltage across the resistor is ~0. The magnitude of the gain becomes ~unity(the output equals the input), and the low signal passes. If $$wCR >> 1$$, then the capacitor acts as a short and all the voltage goes through the resistor. The gain then goes to zero, as does the output.

Now lets consider the case where Z1 is a capacitor and Z2 is a resistor. Our new magnitude of the response becomes
$$\frac{wCR}{(1^2 + (wCR)^2)^{0.5}}$$

At high frequencies, $$ w >> \frac{1}{RC}$$, the capacitor acts like a short and the gain is 1(the signal passes). At low frequencies, the capacitor is an open the output is zero(signal doesn't pass).